# How to check if Double value is negative or not?

Tags: java, double

As title suggests, how do i check if particular `Double` is negative or not. Here is how am getting `Double` instance

```
(Double.parseDouble(data[2])
```

Thoughts, suggestions?

Comment: About the only thing I can think of is if there's some wierd corner case with a negative 0, but still...

Comment: There was indeed an corner that I should have mentioned in the question itself and yes i agree that i should have put in what i tried first, anyways if someone can delete this question then plz do so as it is not worthwhile to have it here.

Comment: Closed because "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors". This question's answer just saved me a lot of time. I hate SO.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. I searched Google for "java double is positive" specifically for the trick to handle the `-0.0` corner case. This was the top result. I can never remember the trick, but I know that java has gotchas when comparing `double`s to `0`. @peter-lawrey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400718/1086034) is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Rachel I suggest changing the accepted answer to (the one with the most votes)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400718/1086034]. (If you can. I don't know if it's allowed on closed questions.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Double v = (Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
if (v<0){
//do whatever?
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. See below.

Answer (score 58):

Being pedantic, `< 0` won't give you all negative numbers.

```
double d = -0.0;
System.out.println(d + " compared with 0.0 is " + Double.compare(d, 0.0));
System.out.println(d + " < 0.0 is " + (d < 0.0));
```

prints

```
-0.0 compared with 0.0 is -1
-0.0 < 0.0 is false
```

`-0.0` is negative but not less than `0.0`

You can use

```
public static boolean isNegative(double d) {
     return Double.compare(d, 0.0) < 0;
}
```

A more efficient, if more obtuse, version is to check the signed bit.

```
public static boolean isNegative(double d) {
     return Double.doubleToRawLongBits(d) < 0;
}
```

Note: Under IEEE-754 a NaN can have the same signed bit as a negative number.

Comment: Hardly pedantic! It's absolutely correct, I've had -0.0 come along more than a few times and insist that it absolutely is greater than or equal to 0, in critical sections where any negative will throw a wrench in the gears. That x >= 0 is true for one particular negative number is something to one should be aware of.

Comment: Cool.  It's worth noting, because you wouldn't necessarily intuit it, that Double.compareTo() explicitly considers 0.0d to be strictly greater than -0.0d.  (Also, Double.equals() works the same way.)

Comment: @matthewfearnley Also true for `Float`

Comment: Absolutely correct

Answer (score 5):

You could test if it is `< 0`:

```
if (Double.parseDouble(data[2]) < 0) {
    // the number is negative
} else {
    // the number is positive
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Double.parseDouble` returns a `double` (primitive) not a `Double`. In this case it doesn't really matter, but it's worth being aware of.

You can use:

```
if (foo < 0)
```

to check whether a value is negative - but be aware that this *isn't* the opposite of

```
if (foo >= 0)
```

due to "not a number" values. It does work with infinite values though.

Answer (score 2):

```
Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
```

Doesn't give you a `Double`, it returns a `double`. If you are assigning it to a `Double`, it gets there via autoboxing. Anyways to see if it is negative compare it to 0?
As in:

```
Double.parseDouble(data[2]) < 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution that I quite like is

```
Double v = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

if (v == Math.abs(v))
{
    //must be positive
}
else
{
    //must be negative
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because it fails to handle -0.0 and is equivalent to but less clear than "x < 0".