# How would you update the values in a hashmap based on prior conditions?

Tags: java, hashmap

Something fundamental about hashmaps and for loops is hard for me to grasp here. What I'm trying to do is add +1 to the value associated with the key based on the Keys method every time the value within the array list is associated with the key string.

So if there are 3 values in the array list that are positive then the hashmap should have the value with the key "positive" updated to 3.

Any help/advice would be appreciated - thank you.

```
public String Keys(double input){

    if (input > 0){
        System.out.println("positive");
    }
    else if (input < 0) {
        System.out.println("negative");
    }
    else if (input == 0) {
        System.out.println("zero");
    }
    return "";
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> increaseValues(ArrayList<Double> inputs){
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("positive", 0);
    hashMap.put("negative", 0);
    hashMap.put("zero", 0);

//What I tried before adding the Keys method.
//This updates the value but the loop won't continue if another input in the 
//arraylist is true.

for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++){
        double input = inputs.get(i);

        if (input > 0){
           hashMap.put("positive", 1);
        } else if (input < 0){
          hashMap.put("negative", 1);
        } else if (input == 0){
          hashMap.put("zero", 1); }
    return hashMap;
}

public void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
    inputs.add(-4.56);
    inputs.add(-4.66);
    inputs.add(0.0);
    inputs.add(6.0);
    inputs.add(-6.99);
    inputs.add(6.97);   
}
```

Comment: Where is the part where you are trying to update the values in hashmap? In "increaseValues" method, you are always setting default value of 0 against all three of your keys.

Comment: And why do you need a map at all here? Why not just three variables?

Comment: Yes sorry I will add what I attempted before I had the Keys method in the code. What I tried was iterating over the arraylist and then updating the hashmap based on a conditional statement but this will only update according to the values in the arraylist once and did not account for multiple values that would require the loop to keep running.

Answer (score 2):

`Map.put(k, v)` always overrides your previous value. You can use the "traditional approach":

```
if (!map.containsKey("positive"))
    map.put("positive", 0);
map.put("positive", map.get("positive") + 1);
```

or better use the new `merge` funtction that is added for exactly such cases:

```
map.merge("positive", 1, (prev, one) -> prev + one);
```

But this whole logic can be greatly shortened by using `Math.signum()` and stream collectors:

```
Map<Double, Long> collect = inputs.stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Math::signum,
                                                                 Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println("positive: " + collect.get(1.0));
System.out.println("negative: " + collect.get(-1.0));
System.out.println("zero: " + collect.get(0.0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with a quick tidy, lets create an `enum` and remove those nasty `String` constants that you don't have defined anywhere:

```
public enum Sign {
    POSITIVE,
    ZERO,
    NEGATIVE;

    public static Sign of(double d) {
        if (d > 0) {
            return POSITIVE;
        }
        if (d < 0) {
            return NEGATIVE;
        }
        return ZERO;
    }
}
```

Now we can trivially write a method to increment the appropriate value:

```
public void increment(final double d, final Map<Sign, Integer> count) {
    count.merge(Sign.of(d), 1, Integer::sum);
}
```

For a quick test:

```
final Map<Sign, Integer> count = new EnumMap<>(Sign.class);

increment(0, count);
System.out.println(count);
increment(-1, count);
System.out.println(count);
increment(1, count);
System.out.println(count);
increment(-2, count);
System.out.println(count);
increment(2, count);
System.out.println(count);
```

Output:

```
{ZERO=1}
{NEGATIVE=1, ZERO=1}
{POSITIVE=1, NEGATIVE=1, ZERO=1}
{POSITIVE=1, NEGATIVE=2, ZERO=1}
{POSITIVE=2, NEGATIVE=2, ZERO=1}
```

So how does this magic work? From [the documentation for `Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction))

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is
>   associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value.
>   Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given
>   remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may
>   be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key.

So it takes the `key` as the first argument to `merge` - in the case `Sign.of(d)`; this selects the correct bucket. If the value mapped to that `key` is `null` then it simply puts a mapping for the `key` to the `value` passed as the second argument - in this case `1`. Otherwise it gets a litte more complicated; it takes the value currently mapped to that key and uses the `remappingFunction` passed as the third argument. This is a `BiFunction<V,V,V>`, so it takes two arguments of type `V`, the `value` type and returns a single one - it merges the two together. Here we use `Integer::sum` to take the existing `value`, the new `value` and return their `sum`.

---

But we can go one step further, we can use a `Stream` to carry this out on an arbitrary `double[]`:

```
public Map<Sign, Long> count(final double[] d) {
    return Arrays.stream(d)
            .mapToObj(Sign::of)
            .collect(groupingBy(identity(), () -> new EnumMap<>(Sign.class), counting()));
}
```

---

Note: I've used an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) here, which is `Map` optimised for using an `enum` as the key.

Comment: You can use `Math.signum()` instead of writing an enum for it, though it is nice and explicit. Otherwise thumbs up for the `merge`.

Comment: If you've implemented an `enum` for sign then it would make sense using `EnumMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Could do @MalteHartwig - I would prefer a `Map` keyed on the appropriate, descriptive, `enum` constant rather than an `int`. That way that `Map` itself describes what it is of.

Comment: @lexicore TBH I didn't want to introduce _too_ many new concepts here.

Comment: That's true, that's what I meant by explicit. It certainly looks nice in the sysout.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it pretty concisely with streams. You need a function which turns value into the `negative`/`zero`/`positive` key. Then just group by this key with a counting collector. It's basically a two-liner:

```
    List<Double> values = Arrays.asList(-4.56,-4.66,0.0, 6.0, -6.99, 6.97);

    Function<Double, String> toKey = v -> v < 0 ? "negative" : (v == 0 ? "zero" : "positive");

    Map<String, Long> result = values
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors
            .groupingBy(
                 toKey,
                 Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you could also use `Math.signum` instead of writing your own check. Otherwise I agree, that using a Collector is a good choice here.

Comment: @MalteHartwig `Math.signum` returns a `double`, this still has to be converted to a string representation. So at the end this won't really help much.

Comment: Also true, but separating the grouping from the ... 
"rendering" keeps each step simple. Nothing against it, though, just wanted to mention it.

Comment: @MalteHartwig It would be simpler only if you solve a slightly different task compared to the one the OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

The method `put` of HashMap maps unique keys with values. It replaces the existing value with the new value in case the provided key is already present in the map.

You need to define a method similar to below.

```
public void addValueToList(Double d, List<Double> inputs , Map<String,Integer> map){
    if( d == null ) return;
    if ( isZero(d) ){
        Integer count =  map.get("zero");
        if(count == null){
            count = 1;
        }else {
             count ++;
        }
        map.put("zero",count);

    }else if( isNegative(d) ) {
        Integer count =  map.get("negative");
        if(count == null){
            count = 1;
        }else {
             count ++;
        }
        map.put("negative",count);
    }else {
        Integer count =  map.get("positive");
        if(count == null){
            count = 1;
        }else {
             count ++;
        }
        map.put("positive",count);
   }
   inputs.add(d);
}
```

For writing method for comparing the value you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10400718/504133